# Incrementing pattern as payload

Tags: scapy

Using scapy, how do I create a set of packets with incrementing payloads?
For example, the first packet's payload (data) must be 1, the second's must be 2, and so on.

I tried this:

```
>>> pkt=(Ether(dst='00:01:02:03:04:05', src='00:06:07:08:09:0a')/ IP(src='192.168.0.1', dst='192.168.0.2', tos=0)/ TCP(sport=(123), dport=123))/(1,20)
```

but I get an error.

If I want to create 10 packets with the source port starting at 123, incrementing by 1 for every packet, and ending at 133. I do this:

```
>>> pkt=(Ether(dst='00:01:02:03:04:05', src='00:06:07:08:09:0a')/ IP(src='192.168.0.1', dst='192.168.0.2', tos=0)/ TCP(sport=(123,133), dport=123))/("x")
>>> pkts=[p for p in pkt]
>>> pkts
```

Which works fine

Update:
I made this script for incrementing ip address:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from scapy.all import IP,TCP
from scapy.utils import wrpcap


if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    payload = sys.argv[1]

print "generating packets..."
ip = IP(dst="192.168.0.2", tos=0)
ip_str=[]
for i in xrange(1, 256):
    temp_ip_str = "192.168.0.%d"%(i)
    ip_str.append(temp_ip_str)
ip.src = ip_str
tcp = TCP(sport=443, dport=80)/(payload*6)
pkt=[p for p in ip/tcp]
wrpcap("%s.cap"%payload, pkt)
```

and it should probably work similar for the payload

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here's a clue: `p=sr(IP(dst="rob.example.com")/ICMP()/Raw((1,5)), timeout=1)` does something.

Comment: Here is another clue: `p=Raw(list("hello%d"%i for i in range(3)))` does something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your payloads to contain the ASCII strings "1", "2", ... "19", "20", then try this:

```
pkt=(Ether(dst='00:01:02:03:04:05', src='00:06:07:08:09:0a')/ 
     IP(src='192.168.0.1', dst='192.168.0.2', tos=0)/ 
     TCP(sport=(123), dport=123)/
     Raw((1,20)))
```

If you want your payloads to contain one byte each, with values 1, 2, ... 20, try this:

```
pkt=(Ether(dst='00:01:02:03:04:05', src='00:06:07:08:09:0a')/
     IP(src='192.168.0.1', dst='192.168.0.2', tos=0)/ 
     TCP(sport=(123), dport=123)/
     Raw(list(chr(x) for x in range(1,21))))
```

In either case, you can confirm what you've got via:

```
wireshark(pkt)
```